# Multiple displays and multiple desktops in MacOS

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, macbook-air

I have my macbook air with an external display, configured with extended desktop like this

[image]

I also have my browser in full screen in a different desktop, shown in the built-in display.

When I "three finger swipe" to go to my browser, the external monitor also switches.

Is it possible to only change desktops in my built-in display, and leave the external display as is (without it also switching and showing a gray background), locked in the first desktop?

Comment: I believe this will be available in OS X 10.9 Mavericks - as evidenced by this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mi6AhogZCeg

Comment: I'm actually trying to do the opposite.. get my external monitor to switch as well.. right now it shows the same thing all the time.

Comment: Found a solution here: http://heggen.org/using-spaces-with-dual-monitors-in-os-x-mavericks/

Answer (score 1):

No. It's unfortunately not possible.

In some applications, you can run an application in full screen on one monitor and move tools from that app to a second monitor, but you can’t have a Full Screen Application AND use your second monitor for other applications.

Comment: I upvoted this as well because I am using full screen now and am unhappy that I can't use dual monitors this way. A workaround is to "maximize" the windows your using by resizing them, but that's totally not the same. I feel your pain. If you noticed, you also can't keep the camera running for facetime and several other apps. Hopefully this will change.